# Elasticsearch - index only part of the object

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to index only some part of the object in `elasticsearch`?

Example:

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/item/1' -d '
{
    "record": {
        "city": "London",
        "contact": "Some person name"
    }
}

$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/item/2' -d '
{
    "record": {
        "city": "London",
        "contact": { "phone": "some-phone-number", "name": "Other person's name" }
    }
}

$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/item/3' -d '
{
    "record": {
        "city": "Oslo",
        "headquarters": { "phone": "some-other-phone-number", 
                          "address": "some address" }
    }
}
```

I want only city name to be searchable, all remaining part of the object I want to leave unindexed and completely arbitrary. For example some fields can change it's type from object to object.
Is it possible to write mapping that allow such behaviour?

**UPDATE**

My final solution looks like this:

```
{
     "test": {
        "dynamic": "false",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I add "dynamic": "false" on the lowest level of my mapping and it works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by disabling dynamic mapping on entire type or just inner object record:

```
"mappings": {
    "doc": {
        "properties": {
            "record": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "city": {"type": "string"}
                },
                "dynamic": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```